# Grails params long array

Tags: grails, parameters

I want to understand how can I handle an array of Long in params. I understand that a Long param can be handled as `params.long('var')` and an array can be handled as `params.list('var')` but not clear on how to handle an array of Long.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by "handle"? You can retrieve a list using `params.list('param')`. If you want to convert that to an array of `Long` use:

```
Long[] arrayOfLong  = params.list('param')
```

Answer (score 5):

I was in the same situation with parameter name of the format `var[]`.  The selected answer didn't work for >1 value and, worse, returns the Long ASCII value for a single value.

In case anyone else is in the same boat, my solution was:

`params.list('var[]').collect({ it as Long })`